# How to find element has specific color using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

Here is my HTML code

```
<ul id="components">
    <li>Computer</li>
    <li>Mouse</li>
    <li>Keyboard</li>
    <li>Printer</li>
    <li>CPU</li>
</ul>
```

```css
#components li:first-child{
    color:red;
}
#components li: nth-child(2){
    color:blue;
}
#components li: nth-child(3){
    color:red;
}
#components li: nth-child(4){
    color:red;
}
#components li: nth-child(5){
    color:green;
}
```

What I need is a jQuery function which can find all the `li` elements in `red` color and can convert the background to yellow

I mean something like

```
$("#components").find(li elements in red color).css("backgound","yellow"); 
// find li elements in red color and change the background to yellow
```

Comment: Use classes and css rules instead. How are styles being set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.filter();`

```js
 $('ul li').filter(function() {
   return $(this).css('color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
 }).each(function() {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="components">
  <li style="color:red">Computer</li>
  <li style="color:blue">Mouse</li>
  <li style="color:red">Keyboard</li>
  <li style="color:red">Printer</li>
  <li style="color:green">CPU</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Sree You don't need to use `each()` after `filter()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use attribute selector `[attr=value]` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1022/)

```
$('ul li[style="color:red"]').css('background', 'yellow');
```

You can also do this with pure CSS

```css
ul#components li[style="color:red"] {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul id="components">
  <li style="color:red">Computer</li>
  <li style="color:blue">Mouse</li>
  <li style="color:red">Keyboard</li>
  <li style="color:red">Printer</li>
  <li style="color:green">CPU</li>
</ul>
```

Update: This is not best way to do this but you could check each li for color and that returns `rbg` and add background [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1024/)

```js
$('ul li').each(function() {
  var color = $(this).css('color');
  if (color == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
})
```

Comment: This is helpful .but I don't want to add `style="color:red"` inline.For better understanding I added inline

Comment: You should mention that in question. How do you set `color: red`?

Answer (score 1):

try that,

```
$('li[style="color:red"]').css('background-color','yellow')
```

Or

```
$('li[style="color:red"]').attr('style','color:red;background-color:yellow;')
```

Or using each() loop

```
var allLi=$('li')
$.each(allLi,function(k,v){
if($(v).attr('style')=='color:red')
{
$(v).css('background-color','yellow')
}
})
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Praveent696/uof4wes6/1/)

Comment: This is helpful .but I have edited my question please check

Comment: if you don't have any reason , you don't have to down vote

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filtering element selection. Use [`style.color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property in function of `filter()` to getting color of element.

```js
$("#components > li").filter(function(){
    return this.style.color == "red";
}).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="components">
    <li style="color:red">Computer</li>
    <li style="color:blue">Mouse</li>
    <li style="color:red">Keyboard</li>
    <li style="color:red">Printer</li>
    <li style="color:green">CPU</li>
</ul>
```