# Change one color in all css style by javascript

Tags: css, colors, prestashop

I have a template with multiples class using one color, can I dynamically change that color to another using javascript?

When the page loads, locate all the div, span, p, h, with color #512a69 and change it to #ef7e8e.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Go look into CSS variables, and how to manipulate their values using JavaScript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306873/how-to-find-element-has-specific-color-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which I'll explain step-by-step.

First, call `colorReplace("#512a69", "#ef7e8e");`. The first value is the target color, and the second is the replacement color.

Inside it, `$('*').map(function(i, el) {` will select all tags in the DOM tree. For each element, its `getComputedStyle(el)` styles array is returned. You can customize the selector for faster processing (e.g. `$('div').map(function(i, el)) {`).

All style attributes containing "color" (e.g. `background-color`, `-moz-outline-color`, etc.), it will be checked if the color value is equal to your target color. If so, it will be replaced with the target color.

Colors are returned like `rgba(0,0,0,0)` or `rgb(0,0,0)`, not like `#FFFFFF`, so a quick conversion is done from rgb to hex for the comparison. That uses the internal `rgb2hex()` function.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

---

```
function colorReplace(findHexColor, replaceWith) {
    // Convert rgb color strings to hex
    // REF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627747/1938889
    function rgb2hex(rgb) {
        if (/^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/i.test(rgb)) return rgb;
        rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);

        function hex(x) {
            return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }
        return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
    }

    // Select and run a map function on every tag
    $('*').map(function(i, el) {
        // Get the computed styles of each tag
        var styles = window.getComputedStyle(el);

        // Go through each computed style and search for "color"
        Object.keys(styles).reduce(function(acc, k) {
            var name = styles[k];
            var value = styles.getPropertyValue(name);
            if (value !== null && name.indexOf("color") >= 0) {
                // Convert the rgb color to hex and compare with the target color
                if (value.indexOf("rgb(") >= 0 && rgb2hex(value) === findHexColor) {
                    // Replace the color on this found color attribute
                    $(el).css(name, replaceWith);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

// Call like this for each color attribute you want to replace
colorReplace("#512a69", "#ef7e8e");
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30724171/1136132