# How can i get specific element with 'document.querySelector' according to 'color' property?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the 'p' element with red color attribute. To do this i wrote the code below but i get a null result. What am i doing wrong?

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
    <script src="./test.js" defer></script>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="p1">red</p>
    <p id="p2">green</p>
    <p id="p3">blue</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
test.js

"use strict"

let element = document.querySelector("p[color='red']");
console.log(element); // logs null
```

**test.css**

```
#p1 {
  color: red;
}

#p2 {
  color: green;
}

#p3 {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Just head over to this other question on stack overflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306873/how-to-find-element-has-specific-color-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to select an element based not on its *HTML attributes*, but on the CSS rules that are applied to it. This can't be done with a plain `querySelector`.

For the general case, iterate over all possibly matching elements and call `getComputedStyle` on each to find the one that matches:

```js
const p = [...document.querySelectorAll('p')]
  .find(p => window.getComputedStyle(p).color === 'rgb(255, 0, 0)');
console.log(p);
```

```css
#p1 {
  color: red;
}

#p2 {
  color: green;
}

#p3 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1">red</p>
<p id="p2">green</p>
<p id="p3">blue</p>
```

Note that for color, you need to use `rgb` syntax.